# How to Replace a Date in String Format with Values ​in a Table

Tags: replacement, list-manipulation

I have a Table generated by reading a set of Excel files using the code:

```
files = FileNames["*.xls", {"D:\\Dados\\"}]
data = Table[
  Import[files[[j]], {"Data", 1, Range[5, 133], {2, 4}}], {j, 1,
   Length[files]}]
```

But unfortunately, the program that generates the spreadsheets is writing the date and time in text format, and the result of the reading (data) is:

```
{{{"2021-08-01 05:47:47", 0.}, {"2021-08-01 05:52:47",
   0.}, {"2021-08-01 05:57:47", 26.3}, {"2021-08-01 06:02:47",
   48.3}, {"2021-08-01 06:07:48", 85.4}, {"2021-08-01 06:12:48",
   178.7}, {"2021-08-01 06:17:48", 260.9}, {"2021-08-01 06:22:49",
   309.1}, {"2021-08-01 06:27:49", 378.5}, {"2021-08-01 06:32:49",
   347.3}, ,...
....
..., {"2021-08-11 16:00:42", 929.7}, {"2021-08-11 16:05:43",
   862.2}, {"2021-08-11 16:10:43", 781.9}, {"2021-08-11 16:15:43",
   716.}, {"2021-08-11 16:20:44", 641.5}, {"2021-08-11 16:25:44",
   575.4}}}
```

I need to have this "date and time" column splited in two columns. One column containing the value of the day and another column containing the value of decimal hour.

Can someone help me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
data = {{"2021-08-01 05:47:47", 0.}, {"2021-08-01 05:52:47", 0.}, 
   {"2021-08-01 05:57:47", 26.3}, {"2021-08-01 06:02:47", 48.3},
   {"2021-08-01 06:07:48", 85.4}, {"2021-08-01 06:12:48", 178.7},
   {"2021-08-01 06:17:48", 260.9}, {"2021-08-01 06:22:49", 309.1}, 
   {"2021-08-01 06:27:49", 378.5}, {"2021-08-01 06:32:49",  347.3}};

ClearAll[splitdates1]
splitdates1 = Map[Flatten] @* MapAt[StringSplit, {All, 1}];

splitdates1 @ data
```

> ```
>  {{"2021-08-01", "05:47:47", 0.}, {"2021-08-01", "05:52:47", 0.},
>   {"2021-08-01", "05:57:47", 26.3}, {"2021-08-01", "06:02:47", 48.3}, 
>   {"2021-08-01", "06:07:48", 85.4}, {"2021-08-01", "06:12:48", 178.7},
>   {"2021-08-01", "06:17:48", 260.9}, {"2021-08-01", "06:22:49", 309.1}, 
>   {"2021-08-01", "06:27:49", 378.5}, {"2021-08-01", "06:32:49", 347.3}}
> ```

```
splitdates1 @ data // Grid[#, Dividers -> All] &
```

[image]

Alternatively, create `DateObject`s and `TimeObject`s from the first column elements:

```
ClearAll[splitdates2]
splitdates2 = Map[Flatten] @*
 MapAt[Apply[{DateObject@#, TimeObject@#2} &]@*StringSplit, {All, 1}];


splitdates2 @ data // Grid[#, Dividers -> All] &
```

[image]

We can also use properties of `DateObject`s to get the desired split:

```
ClearAll[splitdates3]
splitdates3 = Map[Flatten] @*
 MapAt[{DateObject@DateObject[#][{"Year", "Month", "Day"}], TimeObject @ #} &, {All, 1}];


splitdates3 @ data // Grid[#, Dividers -> All] &
```

> same picture

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

```
files = FileNames["*.xls", {"D:\\Dados\\"}]
data = First@Table[
  Import[files[[j]], {"Data", 1, Range[5, 133], {2, 4}}], {j, 1,
   Length[files]}];

data[[All, 1]]=StringSplit /@ data[[All, 1]];
data
```

**Original Answer:**

You can use `StringSplit`

```
data = {{"2021-08-01 05:47:47", 0.}, {"2021-08-01 05:52:47", 
    0.}, {"2021-08-01 05:57:47", 26.3}, {"2021-08-01 06:02:47", 
    48.3}, {"2021-08-01 06:07:48", 85.4}, {"2021-08-01 06:12:48", 
    178.7}, {"2021-08-01 06:17:48", 260.9}, {"2021-08-01 06:22:49", 
    309.1}, {"2021-08-01 06:27:49", 378.5}, {"2021-08-01 06:32:49", 
    347.3}};

StringSplit /@ data[[All, 1]]
```

> {{"2021-08-01", "05:47:47"}, {"2021-08-01",
> "05:52:47"}, {"2021-08-01", "05:57:47"}, {"2021-08-01",
> "06:02:47"}, {"2021-08-01", "06:07:48"}, {"2021-08-01",
> "06:12:48"}, {"2021-08-01", "06:17:48"}, {"2021-08-01",
> "06:22:49"}, {"2021-08-01", "06:27:49"}, {"2021-08-01", "06:32:49"}}

Comment: This is very strange. When I show "date" on the notebook the result doesn't appear with quotes, like

date = {{2021-08-01 05:47:47, 0.}, {2021-08-01 05:52:47,
     0.},...
When I copy and paste into this message the quotes are placed in the text like:

date = {{"2021-08-01 05:47:47", 0.}, {"2021-08-01 05:52:47",
     0.},...

Your suggestion to use StringSplit results in the error:

StringSplit::strse: String or list of strings expected at position 1 in StringSplit[{2021-08-01 05:47:47,0.}].

Also, your solution is removing the column of values. The result must contain 3 columns.

Comment: That was just to give you an idea. See my edit.